# Find the normalizer of a cyclic subgroup of $S_7$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

Let $P\subset S_7$ be a cyclic subgroup of order $7$. Show that the normalizer $N$ of $P$ has order $42$, and find a pair of cycles generating $N$.

**My attempt**

First note that the cyclic subgroup is a Sylow-7 subgroup of $S_7$. Let the number of Sylow-7 subgroups in $S_7$ be denoted $n_7$.

The Sylow-7 subgroups all intersect trivially and are all cyclic, so every nonidentity element in a Sylow-7 subgroup is of order $7$ and the number of elements in $S_7$ with order $7$ is equal to $n_7$ times $6$.

The elements of order $7$ in $S_7$ are the 7-cycles. And there are $7!/7$ of them.

Therefore, $n_7 = 5!$.

Now, to show that $|N|=42$, use the identity: $n_7 = |S_7 : N| = |S_7|/|N|$.

**My question**

First, I can't see why $N$ is generated by a pair of cycles.

Also, I am having trouble writing out explicitly the generators of $N$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: As you noticed, the elements of order $7$ are the $7$-cycles.  WLOG, let $P$ be the group generated by $(1\ 2\ 3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 6\ 7) = \sigma$.  Then clearly $P$ normalizes itself.

If we use the fact than in any group $G$, for two subsets $H,K$ of $G$, we have $$|HK| = \frac{|H| |K|}{|H \cap K|}  $$   we can form a set of order $42$ if we let $H = P$ and $K$ be a group generated by a $6$-cycle. If this $6$-cycle happens to normalize $P$, we've formed a set of order $42$ where each element normalizes $P$. Since $|N_G(P)| = 42$, this set must be $N_G(P)$. So you just need to find a $6$ cycle that normalizes $P$

I will throw in the additional fact that for any $k$-cycle
$(a_1\  a_2\ ... a_k) = x$ and permutation $\tau$, we have that $\tau x \tau^{-1} = (\tau (a_1)\ \tau( a_2) \ ... \tau( a_k))$

Comment: I found $\tau = (2\, 4\, 3\, 7\, 5\, 6)$ with $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = \sigma^3$! Thanks a lot for the help, Dionel!

Comment: Woohoo! Nicely done

Comment: The question asked to show that the normaliser has order $42$, while you seemed to assume this fact in your answer.

Comment: @mkmlp  He was not asking why the normalizer has order 42.  He already showed why in his post.

Comment: @DionelJaime That’s correct! Dionel’s answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again, Dionel!