# How to find the normalizer of $H=\langle (12345)\rangle$ in $S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Let  $H=\langle (12345)\rangle$. Find the normalizer of H in $S_5$.

First I noticed that two cycles are conjugate iff they have the same cycletype and we know that given $g\in S_5$ and $x=(x_1\ldots x_k)\in S_5$, a k-cycle, its conjugate is $gxg^{-1}=(g(x_1)\ldots g(x_k))$, but I do not see how all the information above helps me to determine the normalizer of H. Any tips or maybe a solution on how to find all $g\in S_5$ such that $gHg^{-1}=H$?

Comment: This answers your question [Find the normalizer of a cyclic subgroup of $S_7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209007/find-the-normalizer-of-a-cyclic-subgroup-of-s-7): use the same method, and the fact that $(2354)^{-1}(12345)(2354)=(13524)=(12345)^2.$

Comment: I think I founded it, could you check my answer please?

Comment: You could do it using [SAGE](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup.PermutationGroup_generic.normalizer)

Comment: @AnneBauval why is the fact that $(2354)^{−1}(12345)(2354)=(13524)=(12345)^2$ important. I found the answer and it is a group of order 20 generated by $<(12345),2354)>$, but I do not see how

Comment: The link provided in the first comment above shows you how to prove that your $|N(H)|$ is equal to $20=4|H|,$ and explains (with 6 and 7 instead of 4 and 5, but also coprime) why, if you find a $4$-cycle $c$ normalizing $H$ then $N(H)$ is generated by $c$ and any generator of $H.$ I do not understand how you can simultaneously claim to have "found" this answer and to "not see how".

Comment: @AnneBauval So if we find a 4-cycle that normalizes H and if we use the fact a group is closed under multiplication then the group generated by a 4 and 5 cycle normalizes H. Do we take a 4- cycle in order to find the maximum amount of elements that normalizes H. We could take a 3 cycle but we could have more.  So by taking a 4-cycle we assure that every element that normalizes H is in it.

Comment: Not "then the group generated by *a* [=any] 4 and 5 cycle..." but the two cycles ptecised in my previous comment.  And this does not "use the fact a group is closed under multiplication". There are no 3-cycles in a subgroup of order 20. And yes we take an normalizing element of order 4 so that this element and H generate a subgroup of order 20.

Comment: @AnneBauval I think that I understand it now, but could you clarify one thing for me please. So we took a 4 cycle (2354) for which the conjugation holds that means K=$\langle 2354\rangle < N_{S_5}(H)$. We also know that $H< N_{S_5}(H)$. That means that $HK=\{hk|h\in H, k\in K\}< N_{S_5}(H)$ with order 20. My question is how do we know that this is all of $ N_{S_5}(H)$. Is it because $S_5$ has only subgroups with order 20 60 120 (I did not list the others). And $A_5$ is certainly not the normalizer. So how could we conclude in general that this is the normalizer?

Comment: $S_5$ has many more subgroups. We do not look at them. As commented above: "The link provided in the first comment above shows you how to prove that your |N(H)|
 is equal to 20".